# Nuxtjs 3 navigate after data was loaded

Tags: javascript, typescript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am using Nuxtjs 3. I have pages A and page B.

Page B fetches data from an API.

I want to when navigating from page A to page B, page B shows after the data fetch from API.

Page A:

```
  <div>
    <NuxtLink to="B" />
  </div>
```

Page B:

```
<div>
   content ...
<div>

...
methods: {
async fetchData() {

  let {data} = await useFetch(this.runTimeConfig.public.apiBase + '/website/fetch/index', {
        method: "GET",
        credentials: 'include',
        onResponseError(context) {
          alert("error")
          console.log(context.response._data)
        }
      }
  )
  this.pageConfig = data

},
}
...
```

My problem is page B shows and then data fetch, but I want to first data fetch and then page B render.

Comment: Use a blocking render fetching hook: https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching#usefetch

Comment: Thank you for your response but I couldn't figure out what should id do. @kissu

Comment: Showing more code of the relevant pages may help us move forward.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added more code. @kissu

Comment: If you're using Nuxt3, I recommend the usage of the Composition API (`script setup`). Otherwise, you can use Nuxt2 with its `asyncData` lifecycle hook indeed, that one is [blocking the rendering](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching/).

Comment: Nice! I posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Nuxt3, I recommend the usage of the Composition API (`script setup`).
Otherwise, you can use Nuxt2 with its `asyncData` lifecycle hook indeed, that one is [blocking the rendering](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching/).